# Why did crash our WordPress site?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, crash, cloudways

There is no doubt, our WordPress site is heavy loaded, but why it crashed, and why we couldn't restart it on Cloudways only rollback it?

I see hungreds of similar lines before the crash like:

> [Tue Apr 13 15:12:25.882171 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 6670:tid 139911898322688] [client 89.135.146.241:13425] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS, referer: https://www.palferi.hu/hanganyagok/2006-2007/2007-01-02/

And after the crash, 4 similar line like:

> [Wed Apr 14 10:34:50.809931 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1200:tid 140238550603520] [client 138.197.189.13:52981] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: WordPress adatb\xc3\xa1zis hiba Table 'hudxsgwarf.wpar_posts' doesn't exist a lek\xc3\xa9rdez\xc3\xa9sben SELECT wpar_posts.* FROM wpar_posts LEFT JOIN wpar_term_relationships ON (wpar_posts.ID = wpar_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( \n wpar_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1,86)\n) AND wpar_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'hanganyagok', 'csoportok', 'programok', 'teljess-gre-hangolva') AND (wpar_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wpar_posts.ID ORDER BY wpar_posts.post_date DESC k\xc3\xa9sz\xc3\xadtette require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, do_action_ref_array, WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WPSEO_Sitemaps->redirect, WPSEO_Sitemaps->get_sitemap_from_cache, WPSEO_Sitemaps->refresh_sitemap_cache, WPSEO_Sitemaps->build_sitemap, WPSEO_Sitemaps->build_root_map, WPSEO_Taxonomy_Sitemap_Provider->get_index_links, WP_Query->__construct, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts\n', referer: https://www.palferi.hu/sitemap_index.xml

Do you have any idea what were happen? Cloudways claim, CPU power was short to serve the requests. I do not know.

Comment: It appears someone intentionally or unintentionally caused a denial of service I am not going to specifics of how (I am sure I am not allowed to do that... here)  so I'll keep my mouth shut

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Do you still need assistance?